# Python newb, function ask for exactly one argument, two given

Tags: python

I have the following code below

```
def runRobot(self):
  allActions = ('North','South','East','West','Suck')
  bestActionUtility = 0
  toDo = 'Suck'
  for a in allActions:
    actionUtility = self.getActionUtility(a)
    if(actionUtility > bestActionUtility):
      toDo = a
      bestActionUtility = actionUtility
  # Do lots of robot stuff here!
  self.action = random.choice(['North','South','East','West','Suck'])

def getActionUtility(action):
  return 0
```

I keep getting an error when runRobot is called that tells me I am providing `getActionUtility(action)` with two arguments. I do not see how this is possible. My for loop I think peels off each element of the `allActions` list (array? or is python only lists) and calls `getActionUtility` for each action. Am I wrong?

If more code is needed let me know, but I think this should cover the entire problem.

Comment: It doesn't, because there is no indication in the code you've posted that *these are methods in a class.*

Comment: What does "It doesn't" refer to?

Comment: It refers to the last sentence of your question, which I was replying to. "...I think this should cover the entire problem."

Comment: Oh, Well, the guy below figured it out. I think he used inference or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `self` as first parameter in your `getActionUtility` method. When you invoke the method like this:

```
self.getActionUtility(a)
```

`self` is implicitly passed as first argument to the method. So, just change the method signature to:

```
def getActionUtility(self, action):
    return 0
```